# elasticsearch: How to set custom record count based on a type in search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search request like this:

My docs have a type, and the types like "sport", "health", "news" and etc, and now I want the result count is mapping percent by types:
sport 10%, health 30%, news 60%.

Eg: if I search to get 200 records, I expect that the 200 records include 20 news records, 60 health records and 120 news records.

thanks for any suggest!

johnson

the percent like

Comment: I do not understand why you want Elasticsearch to calculate this for you. Is this not something you can calculate after receiving the results from Elasticsearch?

Comment: This is the customer request, Yes, I think I can calculate after receiving result, but I want to do 1 query to get result, because I think about pagination. for example, if I want to get 500 records, then I can merge to get them, but if we want to display 50 records per page, how can I return records for next page, calculate again?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think the best approach to this is to [Facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html) on the doc types, using a [Terms Facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html). You can then calculate the percentages based on count for each facet (doc type) in combination with the total hits and this calculated percentage will be valid across all paged hits. Only when the query itself is updated will you need to update the  percentages. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: hi Cook, thanks for response. the Terms Facet is using calculate some value after query, but my basic question is how to get result based on type's percentage, I expect to do this using one query, do you have any suggests? thanks again!